# preg_match error Unknown modifier '{'

Tags: php, regex

What's wrong with this?

```
if((preg_match('[a-zA-Z]{1,7}+',$_POST['naam'])) and (preg_match('[^\@\#\<\>\&\*\/]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+!',$_POST['password'])))
```

the first regex i want a string of 1-7 long containing only alphabetic letters.

The second regex i want a string containing letters and numbers with an ! at the end.

Comment: If the first string is supposed to be 1-7 chars long, `{1,7}+` does not make sense - that would match 1-7 chars, but one or more times. So 8 chars would be fine as well etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a delimiter around your regular expressions:

```
if((preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]{1,7}+/',$_POST['naam'])) and (preg_match('/[^\@\#\<\>\&\*\/]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+!/',$_POST['password'])))
```

Comment: Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Thanks it worked. I though that the single quotation marks were the delimiters :D

Answer (score 3):

`{1,7}` - this means 1 to 7

`{1,7}+` - this is awkward, as + denotes that preceding char should be at least once. usually used as `[a-z]+` <-- requires a-z

`{1,7}+` is wrong.